# Functions Error: Impacting Galleries

Tags: functions, gallery, errors

The function below controls an option inside an options panel.  What it does is choose the number of posts being displayed in a particular archive (to_count archives, to_count_home, to_count search are assigned to the homepage, archives.php, and search results respectively).

When I change the number of posts being display it also (for some strange reason) changes the number of images being displayed in a gallery via [gallery] inside a post.  I'm not sure why this is happening, since these codes are not being called inside single.php

```
// Posts per page
add_filter('parse_query', 'wpq_parse_query');
function wpq_parse_query($query)
{
    if($query->is_archive())
    {
        $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = get_option('to_count_archives', 10);
    }
    if($query->is_home())
    {
        $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = get_option('to_count_home', 10);
    }
    if($query->is_search())
    {
        $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = get_option('to_count_search', 10);
} 
    return $query;    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add the condition `$query->is_main_query()` in your `if`-sentences so it won't affect the gallery queries:

```
// Posts per page
add_filter('parse_query', 'wpq_parse_query');
function wpq_parse_query($query)
{
    if(!$query->is_main_query())
    {
        return $query;
    }

    if($query->is_archive())
    {
        $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = get_option('to_count_archives', 1);
    }
    if($query->is_home())
    {
        $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = get_option('to_count_home', 1);
    }
    if($query->is_search())
    {
        $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = get_option('to_count_search', 1);
    } 
    return $query;    
}
```